# vb.net dropdownlist looses it's datasource on pageload or postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, selectedindex

I have a problem with dropdownlist when a button is pressed the bounded data will disappear!
I have absolutely no idea why this is like this!
I have other page that has a bound dropdownlist data as well and it works great but this one get disappear bounded content on page load after pressing the button!
As requested here's my full .vb code
As My files are huge I'm giving you the full link to these files
http://www.mediafire.com/view/8v5e5yjkdpg5780/admin_report.aspx.vb
http://www.mediafire.com/view/xlgt7c2v523rsti/admin_report.aspx

thanks in advance

Comment: why is your dropdownlist for DDL2 has no closing tag or "/>" at the end?

Comment: sorry forgot to add the remaining! thanks and the question eddited @hallie

Comment: i don't see any issues with the code and html setup. have you tried debugging the page or the button click codes?

Comment: @hallie yes and when I click the button at the very first of page load everything on DDL will get disappear such as databounds, datasource, selecteditem or selectedindex, everything! I have no Idea why this is happening. EDIT: I tried with button code empty but it was still the same!

Comment: put brake point on page_load and method then debug what is going on

Comment: @raman thanks for your replay, I had done that before and I'm saying on PAGE_LOAD Everything on every DropDownList that has databound (only those with databounds and only the databounds items) will loos their bound listed data! (also datasource and databounds and so on ...

Comment: IsPostBack is property. please try with removing ()  from IsPostBack

Comment: @chetanyagehlot thanks for your reply that will not fully solve the problem yes I then have my data bound on every postback but then how can I get the selected value from those dropbox? cause then everytime they will loos the data again!

Comment: @Sijav how could it lose the selected data as you are not binding the dropdown again?

Comment: @raman If I knew it I wouldn't disturb you helpful guys and solved it somehow myself :(

Comment: from above code we cant debug the problem. please share full code of both pages. aspx and vb

Comment: @chetanyagehlot thanks and uploaded full code of both pages

Comment: why you set EnableViewState="False" on P tag ?

Comment: @chetanyagehlot I'm gonna cry!!!!!! Thanks a lot! that solved!! I have accidentally put there instead of ddl and forget to erase it! you have saved my day! could you post that so I can mark that as an answer? thanks a lot again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you set EnableViewState="False" on P tag ?
try with removing EnableViewState="False" from P tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL2" runat="server" Style="font-size: 12px;
                color: #0066cc; font-family: Tahoma; direction: rtl;" Width="100px" 
                AppendDataBoundItems="True" >
```

REMOVE

```
  AppendDataBoundItems="True" from above
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, It doesn't change anything, the problem still persists! also look at the DDL1 I have the same problem for that too with no AppendDataBoundItems="True" I have tried the Viewestats too but no success.

Answer (score 0):

add ValueField also:

```
Sub DGDataBind()
    Dim adapter As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    adapter = New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("LoadSomething", connection)
    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Dim param As New Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@something1", Data.SqlDbType.Bit)
    param.Value = 1
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(param)
    param = New Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@something2", Data.SqlDbType.Bit)
    param.Value = 0
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(param)
    GlobalVariables.datas.Clear() 'Public Class GlobalVariables Public Shared datas As New Data.DataSet
    adapter.Fill(GlobalVariables.datas)
    DDL1.DataSource = GlobalVariables.datas.Tables(0)
    DDL1.DataTextField = "rptname"
    DDL1.DataValueField = "ColumnName"
    DDL1.DataBind()
    DDL1.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("empty", "0"))
    DDL1.SelectedIndex = 0
    DDL2.DataSource = GlobalVariables.datas.Tables(0)
    DDL2.DataTextField = "rptname"
    DDL2.DataValueField = "ColumnName"
    DDL2.DataBind()
 End Sub
```

and page load should be like:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
DGDataBind()
End If
```

**Here is the Problem In Your Code:**
    As **IsPostBack** is Property not a method

and don't use inline style, create a css class then use it. as below:

CSS Code:

```
<style>
.ddl1
{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #0066cc; 
    font-family: Tahoma; 
    direction: rtl;
    width=100px;

    }
</style>
```

and HTML code is:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL1" CssClass="ddl1" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

hope this will help you

Comment: thanks for your answer but that did not solved the problem, however you have teach me something that we can have different values and names on a bound! and I really thanks for that, and there's something else datavaluefield will be automatically is set to datatextfield.

Comment: that was not solved the problem and also css code doesn't did any good too :( I'm stuck at nothing!!!! I have another page with this master that is working great and I can access the selected bound value with no problem!